# How to merge two collections which use overlapping auto-increment `_id`?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do you merge two MongoDB collections when both use auto-incrementing
`_id` which start from `0`? The dumps cannot be merged because of
duplicate keys.

This field is the only one that needs to be unique. And it is the only one that blocks the merge. There is no other merge-handling needed since this is a log.

Skip to the “Roadblock” section for the problem I’m having with my
current approach.

#### Problem

Some months ago we migrated an installation (basically we just gave it a
new name). One of the components is MongoDB which stores a log. But
there was an operational problem with restoring the backup of that log,
so the log just had to be turned on and start from scratch.

We now want to restore that backup and merge it with the ongoing
log. This means that all entries from the backup log should go before
the entries that have been created since.

#### Sketch of the solution

1. Create a temporary collection `outcoll`

   - We will drop the existing (running) collection and replace it with
     this one once we are done
2. Use the collection (`second`) that we’re merging into
3. The dump has been read in as the collection `first`
4. We have set up a document in the [counters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v2.2/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) collection which will
   keep track of the new `_id` values, starting from `0` and
   incrementing by one
5. Use an aggregate with `$unionWith` for the merge
6. `$unset` the `_id`
7. `$set` the `_id` by calling the function which increments the helper
   counter document

#### Roadblock

Given this function from the the [aforementioned](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v2.2/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) link:

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.customSequences.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}
```

With:

```
db.second.aggregate(
    [
      { $unionWith: { coll: "first" } },
      {
        $unset: [
          "_id"
        ],
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "_id": getNextSequence("outcoll")
        }
      },
      {
        $out: "outcoll"
      }
    ]
);
```

I get this error:

```
rs1 [primary] <DB>> <expression>
MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: E11000 duplicate key error collection: <DB>.tmp.agg_out.d8426ad6-9906-4c53-90b8-ed910f251d47 index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 5 }
```

All that happens (apparently) is that the counter document is
incremented by one.

Comment: try unsetting the `_id` before and after `union`

Comment: Can you post sample documents of both collections and corresponding expected output to show how conflicts should be resolved?

Comment: @ray There aren’t any conflicts, this is a log. They should just be inserted in chronological order. And the `_id` conflict handled by generating new auto-increments. I’ll add this to the question.

Comment: @sidgate that didn’t work for me

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MTsXqUNL9OQ)?

Comment: @ray Excellent, that works for me! I just have to adjust my question to include `timestamp` (I said to sort by some timestamp but I didn’t say what it was called). Mind making an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea actually works and is very close. The only change I made is using `$setWindowFields` and `$documentNumber` to recompute the sequence.

```js
db.second.aggregate([
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "first"
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "timestamp": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "_id": {
          "$documentNumber": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": "outcoll1"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MTsXqUNL9OQ)

If you need to update back the `counters` collection, perform one extra update after the above query.

```js
db.outcoll.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "seq": {
        "$max": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      collection: "outcoll",
      seq: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "counters",
      "on": "collection",
      "whenMatched": "merge"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qJV6W_vn8i0)